# Format date into a month count and years

Tags: flutter, dart

We have a DateTime value returning from JSON its coming thru as "10/9/2016 4:46:48 PM" .

What we need to do with it is format it to months or years past like so:

10/9/2016 = 3 years in the past.

The value 10/20/2019 = 3 months

Is this possible?

I'm guessing we would need to grab the month and year and subtract from today's date.

Comment: Try using this library instead. https://pub.dev/packages/timeago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would create a function which will calculate difference between today's date and DateTime passed to it. It would look like this

```
String calculateDifference(DateTime dateTime) {
    String text = "months";
    double difference = DateTime.now().difference(dateTime).inDays / 30;

    if (difference > 11) {
      difference = difference / 12;
      text = "years";
    }

    return "${difference.toStringAsFixed(0)} $text";
}
```

So you just need to parse the date from your JSON to DateTime object and pass it to a variable. You can also add one more condition to return value for days

Comment: thanks for the help! I tried it and got an invalid date format the date i'm passing to it is "10/9/2016 4:46:48 PM"

Comment: its erroring when i parse the string here:  double difference = DateTime.now().difference(DateTime.parse(dateOfIncident)).inDays / 30;

Comment: @Sam Cromer yes because DateTime is using ISO8601 format of date so you should change it to that format.

Comment: I removed the time stamp in TSQL and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use .difference on DateTime

```
final dateInThePast = DateTime(2018, 1, 7);
final dateNow = DateTime.now();
final difference = dateNow.difference(dateInThePast).inDays;
```

And then calculate from Days to Months / Years